# System Icons - Windows 10 style

Tags: c#, winforms

I have custom MessageBox which uses SystemIcons. The problem is that they look outdated. See picture bellow containing Warning/Exclamation icon. I want to set icon same as on the top MessageBox.
How could I do it?

Related question - how to extract system icons from dll (I have tried 7-Zip method and Resource Hacker however could not get graphics inside, in Visual Studio however it shows but arranged in a file tree instead of thumbnails).

[image]

I have found "SecurityAndMaintenance_Alert.PNG" file in System32 folder which looks very similar, however border looks thinner and I would like to set exact same Icon if it is possible.

Comment: While writing the question I found a solution. However still decided to share the question as there might be better approach than extracting icons.

I found that icons are located in imageres.dll in System32 folder. To extract the icons I have used greenfish icon editor which is open source. In dll file located icon number 84 for Warning. Saved it and imported to Resource file of the project. That is it, now I have fancy new icon :)

Comment: A better approach is to let your application load icons from Windows system via APIs like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona PInvoke is commonly used, as .NET Framework or .NET Core never covers all necessary Win32 APIs.

Comment: You can use the duplicate to improve your custom advanced message box to show the current operating system icons. Here is an [example](https://github.com/Ordisoftware/Hebrew-Calendar/blob/master/Project/Source/Common/Core/WinForms/MessageBoxEx.cs).

Comment: You need to use [SHGetStockIconInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetstockiconinfo?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [SHGetStockIconInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetstockiconinfo?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

```
var sii = new NativeMethods.SHSTOCKICONINFO();
sii.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.SHSTOCKICONINFO));
NativeMethods.SHGetStockIconInfo(NativeMethods.SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_WARNING,
    NativeMethods.SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON,
    ref sii);
this.pictureBox1.Image = Icon.FromHandle(sii.hIcon).ToBitmap();
```

[image]
[image]

You can see all the [icons here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ne-shellapi-shstockiconid?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

And here is NativeMethods:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class NativeMethods
{
    public const int MAX_PATH = 260;

    [Flags]
    public enum SHGSI : uint
    {
        SHGSI_ICONLOCATION = 0,
        SHGSI_ICON = 0x000000100,
        SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x000004000,
        SHGSI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x000008000,
        SHGSI_SELECTED = 0x000010000,
        SHGSI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000,
        SHGSI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001,
        SHGSI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004
    }
    public enum SHSTOCKICONID : uint
    {
        SIID_DOCNOASSOC = 0,          //Blank document icon (Document of a type with no associated application).
        SIID_DOCASSOC = 1,            //Application-associated document icon (Document of a type with an associated application).
        SIID_APPLICATION = 2,         //Generic application with no custom icon.
        SIID_FOLDER = 3,              //Folder (generic, unspecified state).
        SIID_FOLDEROPEN = 4,          //Folder (open).
        SIID_DRIVE525 = 5,            //5.25-inch disk drive.
        SIID_DRIVE35 = 6,             //3.5-inch disk drive.
        SIID_DRIVEREMOVE = 7,         //Removable drive.
        SIID_DRIVEFIXED = 8,          //Fixed drive (hard disk).
        SIID_DRIVENET = 9,            //Network drive (connected).
        SIID_DRIVENETDISABLED = 10,   //Network drive (disconnected).
        SIID_DRIVECD = 11,            //CD drive.
        SIID_DRIVERAM = 12,           //RAM disk drive.
        SIID_WORLD = 13,              //The entire network.
        SIID_SERVER = 15,             //A computer on the network.
        SIID_PRINTER = 16,            //A local printer or print destination.
        SIID_MYNETWORK = 17,          //The Network virtual folder (FOLDERID_NetworkFolder/CSIDL_NETWORK).
        SIID_FIND = 22,               //The Search feature.
        SIID_HELP = 23,               //The Help and Support feature.
        SIID_SHARE = 28,              //Overlay for a shared item.
        SIID_LINK = 29,               //Overlay for a shortcut.
        SIID_SLOWFILE = 30,           //Overlay for items that are expected to be slow to access.
        SIID_RECYCLER = 31,           //The Recycle Bin (empty).
        SIID_RECYCLERFULL = 32,       //The Recycle Bin (not empty).
        SIID_MEDIACDAUDIO = 40,       //Audio CD media.
        SIID_LOCK = 47,               //Security lock.
        SIID_AUTOLIST = 49,           //A virtual folder that contains the results of a search.
        SIID_PRINTERNET = 50,         //A network printer.
        SIID_SERVERSHARE = 51,        //A server shared on a network.
        SIID_PRINTERFAX = 52,         //A local fax printer.
        SIID_PRINTERFAXNET = 53,      //A network fax printer.
        SIID_PRINTERFILE = 54,        //A file that receives the output of a Print to file operation.
        SIID_STACK = 55,              //A category that results from a Stack by command to organize the contents of a folder.
        SIID_MEDIASVCD = 56,          //Super Video CD (SVCD) media.
        SIID_STUFFEDFOLDER = 57,      //A folder that contains only subfolders as child items.
        SIID_DRIVEUNKNOWN = 58,       //Unknown drive type.
        SIID_DRIVEDVD = 59,           //DVD drive.
        SIID_MEDIADVD = 60,           //DVD media.
        SIID_MEDIADVDRAM = 61,        //DVD-RAM media.
        SIID_MEDIADVDRW = 62,         //DVD-RW media.
        SIID_MEDIADVDR = 63,          //DVD-R media.
        SIID_MEDIADVDROM = 64,        //DVD-ROM media.
        SIID_MEDIACDAUDIOPLUS = 65,   //CD+ (enhanced audio CD) media.
        SIID_MEDIACDRW = 66,          //CD-RW media.
        SIID_MEDIACDR = 67,           //CD-R media.
        SIID_MEDIACDBURN = 68,        //A writeable CD in the process of being burned.
        SIID_MEDIABLANKCD = 69,       //Blank writable CD media.
        SIID_MEDIACDROM = 70,         //CD-ROM media.
        SIID_AUDIOFILES = 71,         //An audio file.
        SIID_IMAGEFILES = 72,         //An image file.
        SIID_VIDEOFILES = 73,         //A video file.
        SIID_MIXEDFILES = 74,         //A mixed file.
        SIID_FOLDERBACK = 75,         //Folder back.
        SIID_FOLDERFRONT = 76,        //Folder front.
        SIID_SHIELD = 77,             //Security shield. Use for UAC prompts only.
        SIID_WARNING = 78,            //Warning.
        SIID_INFO = 79,               //Informational.
        SIID_ERROR = 80,              //Error.
        SIID_KEY = 81,                //Key.
        SIID_SOFTWARE = 82,           //Software.
        SIID_RENAME = 83,             //A UI item, such as a button, that issues a rename command.
        SIID_DELETE = 84,             //A UI item, such as a button, that issues a delete command.
        SIID_MEDIAAUDIODVD = 85,      //Audio DVD media.
        SIID_MEDIAMOVIEDVD = 86,      //Movie DVD media.
        SIID_MEDIAENHANCEDCD = 87,    //Enhanced CD media.
        SIID_MEDIAENHANCEDDVD = 88,   //Enhanced DVD media.
        SIID_MEDIAHDDVD = 89,         //High definition DVD media in the HD DVD format.
        SIID_MEDIABLURAY = 90,        //High definition DVD media in the Blu-ray Disc™ format.
        SIID_MEDIAVCD = 91,           //Video CD (VCD) media.
        SIID_MEDIADVDPLUSR = 92,      //DVD+R media.
        SIID_MEDIADVDPLUSRW = 93,     //DVD+RW media.
        SIID_DESKTOPPC = 94,          //A desktop computer.
        SIID_MOBILEPC = 95,           //A mobile computer (laptop).
        SIID_USERS = 96,              //The User Accounts Control Panel item.
        SIID_MEDIASMARTMEDIA = 97,    //Smart media.
        SIID_MEDIACOMPACTFLASH = 98,  //CompactFlash media.
        SIID_DEVICECELLPHONE = 99,    //A cell phone.
        SIID_DEVICECAMERA = 100,      //A digital camera.
        SIID_DEVICEVIDEOCAMERA = 101, //A digital video camera.
        SIID_DEVICEAUDIOPLAYER = 102, //An audio player.
        SIID_NETWORKCONNECT = 103,    //Connect to network.
        SIID_INTERNET = 104,          //The Network and Internet Control Panel item.
        SIID_ZIPFILE = 105,           //A compressed file with a .zip file name extension.
        SIID_SETTINGS = 106,          //The Additional Options Control Panel item.
        SIID_DRIVEHDDVD = 132,        //Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later. High definition DVD drive (any type - HD DVD-ROM, HD DVD-R, HD-DVD-RAM) that uses the HD DVD format.
        SIID_DRIVEBD = 133,           //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD drive (any type - BD-ROM, BD-R, BD-RE) that uses the Blu-ray Disc format.
        SIID_MEDIAHDDVDROM = 134,     //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-ROM media in the HD DVD-ROM format.
        SIID_MEDIAHDDVDR = 135,       //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-R media in the HD DVD-R format.
        SIID_MEDIAHDDVDRAM = 136,     //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-RAM media in the HD DVD-RAM format.
        SIID_MEDIABDROM = 137,        //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-ROM media in the Blu-ray Disc BD-ROM format.
        SIID_MEDIABDR = 138,          //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition write-once media in the Blu-ray Disc BD-R format.
        SIID_MEDIABDRE = 139,         //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition read/write media in the Blu-ray Disc BD-RE format.
        SIID_CLUSTEREDDRIVE = 140,    //Windows Vista with SP1 and later. A cluster disk array.
        SIID_MAX_ICONS = 174,         //The highest valid value in the enumeration. Values over 160 are Windows 7-only icons.
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct SHSTOCKICONINFO
    {
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public Int32 iSysIconIndex;
        public Int32 iIcon;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
        public string szPath;
    }
    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern Int32 SHGetStockIconInfo(SHSTOCKICONID siid, SHGSI uFlags, ref SHSTOCKICONINFO psii);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LoadIconWithScaleDown` and `LoadIconMetric` are returning modern-looking [standard system icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-icons#icon-types):

```cpp
HRESULT ret = LoadIconWithScaleDown(NULL, IDI_WARNING, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON), &icon);
HRESULT ret = LoadIconMetric(NULL, IDI_WARNING, LIM_LARGE, &icon);
```

[image: IDI_APPLICATION]
[image: IDI_ERROR]
[image: IDI_INFORMATION]
[image: IDI_QUESTION]
[image: IDI_SHIELD]
[image: IDI_WARNING]
[image: IDI_WINLOGO]